Origen de la expresión "gramática parda"
El DLE indica que gramática parda es:

Habilidad para conducirse en la vida y para salir a salvo o con ventaja de situaciones comprometidas.

No veo ninguna relación con gramática


adj. gramatical.
m. y f. Especialista en gramática.
f. Parte de la lingüística que estudia los elementos de una lengua, así como la forma en que estos se organizan y se combinan.
f. Tratado de gramática.
f. Tradicionalmente, arte de hablar y escribir correctamente una lengua.
f. Antiguamente, estudio de la lengua latina.
f. Ling. Representación de la competencia lingüística de los hablantes, especialmente en lo relativo a la morfología, la sintaxis y ciertos aspectos del léxico.


ni con pardo, parda:


adj. Dicho de un color: Semejante al de la tierra o al de la piel del oso, y que tira a marrón o a rojizo. U. t. c. s. m.
adj. De color pardo.
adj. Dicho especialmente de las nubes o del día nublado: oscuro (‖ sin luz o claridad).
adj. Dicho de la voz: Que no tiene timbre claro y que es poco vibrante.
adj. Ant., Arg., Ec., Hond., Méx., Perú, Ur. y Ven. p. us. mulato (‖ nacido de negro y blanca, o de blanco y negra). U. m. c. s.
m. leopardo.


¿Alguna idea de cómo, cuándo y por qué se formó esa expresión?

Hay alguna forma de ser más evidente que haciendo 3 títeres, todos con el mismo nombre?

Aparece en el Diccionario de la lengua española de la Real Academia Española de 1734, en el cual se explica que en este contexto el adjetivo parda se usa «porque su método en hablar es basto y rudo».
Gramática parda es una expresión o paremia que describe la inteligencia natural o aprendida que poseen algunas personas que carecen de estudios. Por extensión, es la habilidad de las personas que salen airosas de las situaciones comprometidas.
La expresión suele ser peyorativa. Es coloquial y propia del español europeo, aunque actualmente está en desuso. Se ignora su origen, si bien algunos apuntan a que, en la sociedad estamental, el pardo era el color que identificaba a los estratos más bajos de la sociedad. Eran precisamente los miembros de la clase baja, sin formación académica, a quienes se atribuía la gramática parda.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1tica_parda
*Los pardos en la época colonial
En la época colonial americana, los europeos solían calificar como pardos a los descendientes de negros que se mestizaron con los conquistadores y con los aborígenes. Se trataba de personas, por lo tanto, que no eran mulatas (hijos de negros y blancos) ni mestizas (hijos de aborígenes y blancos).
La calificación de pardo respondía a la división de la sociedad en razas, que era frecuente en aquella época. Los pardos solían tener la piel amarronada, más oscura que los europeos pero más clara que los esclavos africanos.*
https://definicion.de/pardo/
